# Why would a pre-build event failed with error code 3 in a TeamCity build?

Tags: c++, teamcity, protocol-buffers, pre-build-event

I am using TeamCity for Continuous Integration. One of my projects in a solution is having a pre build event. It is working fine when I build the project locally. However In TeamCity, the build failed with error code 3. Pre build event is for building Google Protocol buffer's proto file and creating C++ header and C++ source files.

Following is the pre build event:

```
protoc --proto_path=<SourceDir> --cpp_out=<destinationDir> <SourceDir\protofileName1> <SourceDir\Protofilename2>
```

Why I am getting this error in TeamCity but not locally ? Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: Try running the build manually on teamcity build agent and see what errors do you get.

Comment: I tried. It is failing while building the project which is having pre-build event.

Comment: My c++ knowledge is not great I am afraid. But looks like the error is more related to c++ rather than teamcity.